# Shopify API Error while trying to deserialize arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, shopify, rails-activejob

This morning my app started to crash (`Error while trying to deserialize arguments`) because of some Shopify jobs that couldn't find a model (`products_update_job`).

After further investigation, I found that the code I've written in those jobs didn't even try to search for a model, but merely deleted some Memcached tags.

I've been using the `shopify_app` gem to set up the webhooks and process them.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of digging and a bit of luck, I noticed that the webhooks response from Shopify contained a new field `admin_graphql_api_id: gid://shopify/Product/817915723823`. Then I started to do some more digging and learning about [Global ID](https://github.com/rails/globalid) to find that "Support is automatically included in Active Record."

So what happened was that Shopify started, overnight, to send the `admin_graphql_api_id` field that automatically triggered the model search, messing with my app.

**The fix** was to add an initializer that bypasses the model search, doing nothing.

I could use this feature to automatically find models but at times the app receives webhooks with products that aren't there anymore.

`config/initializers/global_id.rb`

```
GlobalID::Locator.use :shopify do |gid|
  # do nothing
end
```

**Update**

One quick fix is to filter out that param

```
def deserialize(job_data)
  sanitized_data = recursive_delete_gids(job_data)
  super(sanitized_data)
end

private

def recursive_delete_gids(hash)
  hash.each do |key, value|
    case value
  when String
    hash.delete(key) if value.start_with? 'gid://'
  when Hash
    recursive_delete_gids(value)
  when Array
    value.each do |array_value|
      recursive_delete_gids(array_value) if array_value.is_a? Hash
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: following the discussion [here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/issues/600), this solution works only if you have that model (`Product`). If you don't have it, it will still fail in the locator.

Comment: haha. no need. I know the exact feeling.

you can keep an eye on [this](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/issues/600) thread for a more permanent fix.

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly the identical problem yesterday from 10 am EST to ~6 pm. My app receives order payloads via webhook and queues them for processing using delayed_jobs. The error I got:

E, [2018-06-18T22:25:43.927114 #51] ERROR -- : 2018-06-18T22:25:43+0000: [Worker(host:e069195b1b97 pid:51)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=15571) (queue=webhook) FAILED (4 prior attempts) with ActiveJob::DeserializationError: Error while trying to deserialize arguments: uninitialized constant Order

I believe this is caused by this attribute, that apparently is no longer being sent:

admin_graphql_api_id: gid://shopify/Order/516.......

I'm going to chnage my app to write the payloads off to a new table, and only serialize to delayed_jobs the ID of the payload record.

Comment: Yeah. They said they are considering not to send that attribute for now, until they announce it properly.

Comment: I would wait for a proper solution to appear. I think the `shopify_app` gem will be updated.